# getView not called on baseAdapter class using Android Studio

Tags: java, android, listview

I have use this class extends base adapter display values. Below code working eclipse correctly. but me newly created project using Androi Studio there this code getview function not call or working. 
i also check getcount . getcount values available.

```
public class CustomAdapterChatActivity extends BaseAdapter {
    ArrayList<ChatUsersDetailsBean> mBeans = new ArrayList<ChatUsersDetailsBean>();
    Context mcontext;
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    CommonUtil commonUtil;
    public CustomAdapterChatActivity(Context context,
            ArrayList<ChatUsersDetailsBean> mBeans) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        mcontext = context;
        this.mBeans = mBeans;       
        commonUtil = new CommonUtil(context);
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }        
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mBeans.size();
    }        
    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }        
    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }       
    public class Holder {
        TextView name;
        TextView content;
    }        
    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.e("getView",""+"getView");
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(
                    R.layout.chat_listview_layout_screen, null);
        }
        setAttributes(position, convertView);

        convertView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub                  
                click(position);
            }
        });
        return convertView;
    }        
    public void click(int position) {
        Intent mintent = new Intent(mcontext, ChatViewBackgroundActivity.class);
        mintent.putExtra("name", mBeans.get(position).getOpponent_name());
        ((ChatActivity) mcontext).startActivityForResult(mintent, 1);
    }
    public void setAttributes(final int position, View convertView) {
        Holder holder = new Holder();       
        holder.imgdispatcher = (ImageView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.chat_list_iv_profilepic);
    }
```

Please help me. i struggle this part.
 No error will be displayed. 
 i check getview run or not that time getview not working anytime.
this code any changes needed

Answer (score 0):

Change your getView() method in your adapter class like below code:

```
public View getView (final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
    if( convertView == null ){
        //We must create a View:
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_list_item, parent, false);
    }
    //Here we can do changes to the convertView
    return convertView;
}
```

While adding newly inflated view, try to avoid passing null as view root. Lint will now warn you not to pass in null for root. Your app won’t crash in this scenario, but it can misbehave. When your child View doesn’t know the correct LayoutParams for its root ViewGroup, it will try to determine them on its own using [generateDefaultLayoutParams](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#generateDefaultLayoutParams()).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. i change code but no changes in executing   
if (convertView == null) {
   convertView = inflater.inflate(
     R.layout.chat_listview_layout_screen , parent, false);

  }

Comment: getView method i print log.e it's not printed. i think the getview method not working fully

Comment: @AbiK Check with your Holder class. You didn't declare ImageView imgdispatcher on Holder class and TextView name, TextView content are not initialized with findViewById() in setAttributes() method. Try to fix that.

Comment: that code little large so i remove here. that coding perfectly working eclipse project. same class and adapter using android studio. android studio project only i faced this problem

Comment: i have one doubt,. latest sdk version depreciate this code

Comment: @AbiK The [BaseAdapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html) class API has no change with latest SDK Version.

Comment: below i have edited and updated modified code but now also getView function not working

Answer (score 0):

@AbiK If you already done like I mentioned on above comment means, use below code of modified getView() method and setAttributes() method. I hope It works for you.

```
        public class CustomAdapterChatActivity extends BaseAdapter {
        ArrayList<ChatUsersDetailsBean> mBeans;
        Context mcontext;
        LayoutInflater inflater;
        CommonUtil commonUtil;

        public CustomAdapterChatActivity(Context context,
                                         ArrayList<ChatUsersDetailsBean> mBeans) {
            mcontext = context;
            this.mBeans = mBeans;
            commonUtil = new CommonUtil(context);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mBeans.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return position;
        }

        public class Holder {
            TextView name;
            TextView content;
            ImageView imgdispatcher;
        }

        public Holder setAttributes(final int position, View convertView) {
            Holder holder = new Holder();
            holder.imgdispatcher = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.chat_list_iv_profilepic);
            // holder.name=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.); // declare Id
            // holder.content=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.); // declare Id
            return holder;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            Holder holder = null;
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)
                    mcontext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.chat_listview_layout_screen, parent, false);
                holder = setAttributes(position, convertView);
                convertView.setTag(holder);
            } else {
                holder = (Holder) convertView.getTag();
            }
            convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    click(position);
                }
            });
            return convertView;
        }

        public void click(int position) {
            Intent mintent = new Intent(mcontext, ChatViewBackgroundActivity.class);
            mintent.putExtra("name", mBeans.get(position).getOpponent_name());
            ((ChatActivity) mcontext).startActivityForResult(mintent, 1);
        }


    }
```